# Regular expression for finding a word

Tags: regex, expression

I have a little problem. I want to find words "dataLayer" and "rating" in this text :

> script> dataLayer = [{
>   'category': 'Lifestyle', 'rating' : 'U',
>      'unused' : 'No', 'adult' : 'No', 'pda' : 'No', 'hasAds' : 'No',
>     'lang' : 'en' }];

I was trying with dataLayer[^r]* but its stack in word"category". Even if i add "rating" in square brackets it doesn't help.

Help!

Comment: Regex is not what you want here.

Comment: Do you mean you need to get all the words in between dataLayer and rating?

Comment: I have task to do it with regex.

Comment: @TomszComasz How does this have to do with C?

Comment: I i need to find "rating" but i put here only fragment of big text so, first need have to find "dataLayer" who precedens "rating"

Comment: `dataLayer[^r]*` will match `dataLayer = [{ 'catego`. How was that attempt related to what you want?

Comment: They are right here: "script> **dataLayer** = [{ 'category': 'Lifestyle', '**rating**' : 'U', 'unused' : 'No', 'adult' : 'No', 'pda' : 'No', 'hasAds' : 'No', 'lang' : 'en' }];"

Comment: I was trying with >dataLayer[^r]*rating

Comment: What is the expected outcome for this example?

Comment: dataLayer = [{ 'category': 'Lifestyle', 'rating

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(\bdataLayer\b.*?\brating\b)
```

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zV0sE5/1)